# Location + Path in web.config not working in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

Just created a new Asp.Net Core MVC App and published it to Azure.

By adding the location/path element to a web.config and re-publishing the site.... my azure-app is immediately broken.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="authenticate" allowOverride="true">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Why is the below not working in Azure Web App?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below code, assuming you want to restrict user to access anything under authenticate folder:-

The following web.config example would apply any settings within the  elements only to any resources located within the /authenticatedirectory of the site:

```
 <location path="~/authenticate" allowOverride="true">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

If it doesn't work, can you enable the  under system.web and let me know what errors are you getting.